# Como identificar um número específico em um valor numérico qualquer?

Tags: c, algoritmo

Por exemplo, minha variável `valor` *(tipo inteiro)* tem o valor **1354**, repare que o numero **13** aparece neste valor numérico. Como posso identificar um numero especifico em outro valor numérico qualquer?
*Eu gostaria de um exemplo em C.*

Segue o enunciado do problema:

*A China está construindo um elevador espacial, que permitirá o lançamento de sondas e satélites a
um custo muito mais baixo, viabilizando não só projetos de pesquisa científica como o turismo espacial.
No entanto, os chineses são muito supersticiosos, e por isso têm um cuidado muito especial com
a numeração dos andares do elevador: eles não usam nenhum número que contenha o dígito “4” ou a
sequência de dígitos “13”. Assim, eles não usam o andar 4, nem o andar 13, nem o andar 134, nem o
andar 113, mas usam o andar 103. Assim, os primeiros andares são numerados 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
11, 12, 15, 16, . . .
Como o elevador espacial tem muitos andares, e eles precisam numerar todos os andares do elevador,
os chineses pediram que você escrevesse um programa que, dado o andar, indica o número que deve
ser atribuído a ele*

Indentifiquei uma forma de verificar se o ultimo algarismo termina com 4, segue o exemplo:

```
int andar(int numero)
{
    int sobra = 0;
    int resultado;

    sobra = numero % 10;

    if (sobra == 4)
    {
        resultado = numero + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        resultado = numero;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Minha duvida e como identificar o 13 e o 4 em um numero qualquer.

Comment: Você quer saber se existe uma sequência de dígitos dentro dos dígitos de um número? Já fez alguma coisa? Está com alguma dúvida específica? Algum problema no que está fazendo? Mostre o que tentou.

Comment: O problema aqui é identificar se o ultimo algarismo termina com **4**, este eu solucionei, já este que citei é identificar o numero 13 em um determinado valor, por exemplo: 413 tem o numero 13 já 414 não tem, deve haver alguma função matemática para solucionar isto.

Comment: Só precisa ver se está no final? Ou pode estar em qualquer posição?

Comment: Em qualquer posição, por exemplo: 42134 tem o 13 neste valor. E meio que uma pesquisa dentro de um valor **inteiro**.

Comment: Eu não faria matematicamente, eu converteria para *string* e procuraria nela. Então, mostrei como fez o outro , como está tentando fazer este.

Comment: Foi editar a pergunta e colocar o enuciado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converte para string e procura a substring.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int ProcuraNumero (int NumeroProcurado, int NumeroAlvo) {
    char NumeroProcuradoString[16];
    char NumeroAlvoString[16];

    sprintf (NumeroProcuradoString, "%d", NumeroProcurado);
    sprintf (NumeroAlvoString, "%d", NumeroAlvo);

    return strstr (NumeroAlvoString, NumeroProcuradoString) != NULL ? 1 : 0;
}

int main(void) {
    printf("%d:", ProcuraNumero (13, 1354)); // 1 = Encontrou.
    printf("%d:", ProcuraNumero (13, 1054)); // 0 = Não encontrou.
    return 0;
}
```

Exemplo rodando aqui: http://ideone.com/K1WyIc

Comment: Vou testar aqui.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: É interessante elucidar porque é necessária a conversão para string. "1354" para o computador não é o número, mas a representação de um número (internalizado como binário) em base 10. Dizer que "1354" contem "13" faz sentido para a representação do número, mas não para o valor em si.

Answer (score 6):

A solução para o problema acima, é utilizar a função do @Alexandre Borela `ProcuraNumero(int NumeroProcurado, int NumeroAlvo)` em um *loop for*.

Solução:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int ProcuraNumero(int, int);

int main(void)
{
    int n_andar , i, treze, quatro;

    printf("\nNumero do andar: ");
    scanf("%i", &n_andar);

    for (i = 0; i < n_andar; i++)
    {
        treze = ProcuraNumero(13, n_andar);

        quatro = ProcuraNumero(4, n_andar);

        if ((quatro == 1) || (treze == 1))
        {
            n_andar += 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\nNovo numero do andar: %i\n\n", n_andar);
}

int ProcuraNumero(int NumeroProcurado, int NumeroAlvo)
{
    int resultado;

    char NumeroProcuradoString[16];
    char NumeroAlvoString[16];

    sprintf(NumeroProcuradoString, "%d", NumeroProcurado);
    sprintf(NumeroAlvoString, "%d", NumeroAlvo);

    resultado = strstr(NumeroAlvoString, NumeroProcuradoString) != NULL ? 1 : 0;

    return resultado;
}
```